# Unable to connect cassandra with python

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

I am trying to connect to cassandra from python , I have installed `cassandra` as `pip install pycassa`.When i am trying to connect to the `cassandra` i am getting the following exception

```
from pycassa.pool import ConnectionPool
pool = ConnectionPool('Keyspace1')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycassa/pool.py", line 382, in __init__
self.fill()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycassa/pool.py", line 442, in fill
conn = self._create_connection()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycassa/pool.py", line 431, in _create_connection
(exc.__class__.__name__, exc))
pycassa.pool.AllServersUnavailable: An attempt was made to connect to each of the servers twice, but none of the attempts succeeded. The last failure was TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:9160
```

I am using python 2.7.
What is the problem, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `listen_address` set to in your cassandra.yaml?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23, listen address is default `localhost:9160`

Comment: You shouldn't specify the port as a part of `listen_address`.

Comment: For anyone still looking for a sample code, here i have posted one: https://github.com/hardikvasa/database-journal

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try specifying the host:

pool = ConnectionPool('Keyspace1', ['server_node_here:9160'])

Comment: also...any reason you're not using the datastax driver? [I know that's not helpful, but since the official datastax ones are out, I'd use them if I were starting out.]

Comment: I tried this too from this url http://pycassa.github.io/pycassa/tutorial.html#connecting-to-cassandra   ,but not solved

Comment: can you see if cassandra is running via nodetool? is the network port open? Could you also gist your cassandra.yaml file?

Comment: that port is not running

Comment: You'll need to point the connectionpool to at least one running, accessible cassandra node for it to work.

Comment: I just downloaded pycassa and tried his code above, and it connected for me.  At this point, I'm thinking that there's something amiss with his Cassandra config.

Answer (score 0):

**General way to connect Cassandra with python.**

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster  
cluster = Cluster()    #for connecting on localhost  
cluster = Cluster(['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2']) #*for connecting on clusters (comment this line, if you are connecting with localhost)*  
session = cluster.connect('testing')
```

**You can also connect using model class with python**

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns  
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import  Model  
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table  
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection  
import uuid  
from datetime import datetime  

connection.setup(['127.0.0.1'], "testing")  #testing is the keyspace
```

**For detail information for model class implementation take a look**: https://github.com/vishal-kr-yadav/NoSQL_Databases